# What do you call the prongs of an electrical plug?

Tags: single-word-request

I speak German on a daily basis and I don't know what to call the prongs of an electrical plug. This makes me so uncomfortable that I have to ask in English about it. I have searched the internet to find out, but couldn't find a schematic showing the name of the prongs in German. Are they "Zinken", "Zacken", "Sporne" or even something else? Who's the electrician to tell me?

[image: an electrical plug showing the prongs prominently]

and the [original image link](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1tOJjNVXXXXX7apXXq6xXFXXXn/1pcs-EU-Plug-Adapter-2-Pin-to-EU-2-Round-Pin-Plug-Socket-Eletronic-Digital-European.jpg), although I don't expect it to last for a very long time:

Comment: maybe it is helpful to add a picture to show the unknown part. Not because the answer sounds invalid - only to visualize it for future readers.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm for people who have never seen an electrical plug?

Comment: @JasonC: for the ones that realizes that dictionaries with Zacken and Zinken don't help to translate "those things" called prongs in english. Otherwise the question would be obsolete if a dictionary is sufficient.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm you know what, I am going to honor that request

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These are called

## *Stifte* (singular: *der Stift*)

or *Kontaktstifte*. There are *Rundstifte* like in continental Europe and *Flachstifte* like in the UK and the US.